# Probability space and independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, dice

I am studying probability theory and one of the questions that I have faced is this. The problem is that I either don't know where to go about with this question or even if I do do something about it, I have no way of knowing if I'm on the right path. Is it possible to please help explain this?

> Given a three-sided biased die. The probability of throwing $2$ or $3$ is $k$ times higher than the probability of throwing $1$. Compute the probability space. Show that the event $A$ = ‘number is greater than $1$’ and $B$ = ‘number is less than $3$’ are not independent.

Answer (score 2):

If you throw the die, then you may get one element from $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$. You also know that 
$$\mathbb P(2) = \mathbb P(3) = k \mathbb P(1),$$
where I've omitted the set notation brackets and interpreted "$k$ times more than other" as that (could be $k+1$ instead).

Since $1 = \mathbb P(\Omega) = \mathbb P(1) + \mathbb P(2) + \mathbb P(3) = (2k+1)\mathbb P(1)$, then $\mathbb P(1) = 1/(2k+1)$ and $\mathbb P(2) = \mathbb P(3) = k/(2k+1)$. Therefore, we have

$$\mathbb P(A) = 1 - \mathbb P(1) = \frac{2k}{2k+1},\qquad\mathbb P(B) = 1 - \mathbb P(3) = \frac{k+1}{2k+1}.$$

The events are not indendent because $$\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(2) = \frac{k}{2k+1} \ne \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) = \frac{2k(k+1)}{(2k+1)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Although the denominator should be squared though correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should. I corrected it!